# Run icCube with JDK 10

Tags: java, jaxb, java-10, iccube

I started icCube with a JDK 10 installed. I got a class not found exception:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class crazydev.iccube.server.IcCubeServer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

It sounds like JDK 10 doesn't include JAXB or package has changed.

The requirements indicates that it can be runned on JDK8 or higher, do I miss something on my server configuration ?

Many thanks.

Comment: JAXB is indeed not included by default in JDK 9 or newer. See: [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

icCube requires Java 8 to run (JRE 9/10/11 are not supported yet). The download page has been updated accordingly.